# issue with typing an object Typescript error - no index signature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an object that I need to type, but am unsure how to do this.
The following is the error I am seeing and my code is below.

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ LIV: string; MAN:
>   string; LDN: string; }' has no index signature. [7017]

```
type Props = {
    city: string;
    cityMap: {
        LIV: string;
        MAN: string;
        LDN: string;
    };
};

const Cities = ({ city }: Props) => {
    const cityMap = {
        LIV: 'Liverpool',
        MAN: 'Manchester',
        LDN: 'London'
    };

    const city = cityMap[city];
    return <>{city}</>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

With `noImplictAny` typescript will not let you index into objects with arbitrary strings (as this is not really type safe and the result of such an index operation would implicitly be `any`)

There are several possible solutions.

Change the type of `city` to be `keyof Props['currencyMap']`

```
type Props = {
    city: keyof Props['currencyMap'];
    currencyMap: {
        LIV: string;
        MAN: string;
        LDN: string;
    };
};

const Cities = ({ city }: Props) => {
    const cityMap = {
        LIV: 'Liverpool',
        MAN: 'Manchester',
        LDN: 'London'
    };

    const cityName = cityMap[city];
};.
```

Or use a type assertion to tell the compiler you are sure `city` will be an apropriate key:

```
const Cities = ({ city }: Props) => {
    const cityMap = {
        LIV: 'Liverpool',
        MAN: 'Manchester',
        LDN: 'London'
    };

    const cityName = cityMap[city as keyof Props['currencyMap']];
};
```

Or you can use a check to ensure `city` is an expected key with a custom type guard:

```
const Cities = ({ city }: Props) => {
    const cityMap = {
        LIV: 'Liverpool',
        MAN: 'Manchester',
        LDN: 'London'
    };
    const isCity = (c: string): c is keyof Props['currencyMap'] => c in cityMap; 
    if (isCity(city)) {
        cityMap[city];
    }else { /* What now ? error ? */ }
};
```